# Dot product between 2 random vectors

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, variance, covariance

I have 2 independent 2-dimenstional random vectors $A$ and $B$.

$$ A = [a_1, a_2] $$
and
$$ B= [b_1, b_2] $$

The variance of the elements of A are identical ($Var[a_1] = Var[a_2] = \sigma^2_a$).
The variance of the elements of B are also identical ($Var[b_1] = Var[b_2] = \sigma^2_b$), however they are correlated by $\rho$.

I need to take the dot product between A and B, and somehow isolate $\sigma^2_a$.

Could you please tell me if my reasoning is correct ?

\begin{align}
Y &= A \cdot B \\[0.7em]
& = a_1b_1 + a_2b_2 \\[0.7em]
Var[Y] &= Var[a_1b_1] + Var[a_2b_2] + 2Cov(a_1b_1, a_2b_2) \\[0.7em]
&= Var[a_1]Var[b_1] + Var[a_1]Var[b_1] + 2\sigma^2_a \ Cov(b_1, b_2) \\[0.7em]
&= \sigma^2_a \left(Var[b_1] + Var[b_2] + 2Cov(b_1, b_2)  \right) \\[0.7em]
&= 2 \sigma^2_a \ \sigma^2_b(1+ \rho)
\end{align}

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Do they have mean zero? Are the elements of $A$ uncorrelated?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Thanks for reminding me. Yes; both A and B are mean zero. And, Yes, the elements of A are uncorrelated

Comment: In that case, the covariance term should be zero:$$E[a_1a_2b_1b_2]=\underbrace{E[a_1a_2]}_{=0}E[b_1b_2]$$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for pointing that out, I fixed that

Comment: As @Golden_Ratio said, you should have found $2Cov(a_1b_1, a_2b_2)=0$ (or if the $a_i$ had correlation $\rho_a$ then equal to $2 \rho_a \rho_b \sigma^2_a \sigma^2_b$) and so a final result of  $2 \sigma^2_a  \sigma^2_b$ (or $2 \sigma^2_a  \sigma^2_b(1+\rho_a\rho_b)$)

Comment: @Henry I don't understand why the covariance term would be zero. Since $cov(x,y) = \rho \sqrt{var[x]var[y]}$, then $cov(b_1, b_2) = \rho \sqrt{var[b_1]var[b_2]}$, right ?

Comment: How did you get from $2Cov(a_1b_1, a_2b_2)$ to $2\sigma^2_a \ Cov(b_1, b_2)$?

Comment: @Henry, I guess I was mistaken. So would it be OK to say that : $cov[a_1b_1, a_2b_2]=cov[a_1, a_2]cov[b_1, b_2]$ and since $a_1$ and $a_2$ are uncorrelated, $cov[a_1, a_2]=0$ and therefore  $cov[a_1b_1, a_2b_2]=0$ ? I'm just surprised that if $b_1$ and $b_2$ are correlated, it wouldn't affect the variance